# Code contract: requires unproven source != null

Tags: c#, code-contracts

After reading over some of the other responses to this type of question I am still left with the warning. In this snippet I pull a UserActivation from my database. By this point there will always be at least one UserActivation. If there is more then one something has gone all pear shaped... I followed some other instructions on how to squelch the warning regarding an unproven source but to no avail.The warning is: Warning   83  CodeContracts: requires unproven: source != null on line 161, see method below for the specific line.

This is the method

```
    private static UserActivation GetUserActivation(Guid userId)
    {
        UserActivations userActivations = UserActivation.GetUserActivationsByUser(userId: userId);

        Contract.Assume(userActivations != null);

        if (userActivations.Count() > 1) // Line Number 161
            throw new Exception("More then one user action found in database");

        return userActivations[0];
    }
```

I am using CC version 1.4.40602.0, As requested here is the UserActivations declaration.

```
public class UserActivations : BusinessListBase<UserActivation>
{
    #region Constructors
    internal UserActivations()
    {
    }

    internal UserActivations(IList<UserActivation> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    internal UserActivations(IEnumerable<UserActivation> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }
```

And here is the GetUserActivationByUser method

```
    public static UserActivations GetUserActivationsByUser(User user = null, Guid userId = new Guid())
    {
        Contract.Requires(user != null || userId != null, "Either user or userId must have a value");
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<UserActivations>() != null);

        Guid id = new Guid();
        if (user != null)
            id = user.Id;
        else
            id = userId;

        return new UserActivations(StorageManager.SelectAll(
            Criteria.And(
            Criteria.EqualTo("UserId", id),
            Criteria.EqualTo("Deleted", false))));
    }
```

The original code was:

```
Public static UserActivations GetUserActivationsByUser(User user = null, Guid userId = new Guid())
    {
        Guid id = new Guid();
        if (user != null)
            id = user.Id;
        else
            if (userId != Guid.Empty)
                id = userId;
            else
                throw new Exception("Either user or userId must have a value");

        UserActivations uas = new UserActivations(StorageManager.SelectAll(
            Criteria.And(
            Criteria.EqualTo("UserId", id),
            Criteria.EqualTo("Deleted", false))));

        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<UserActivations>() != null);

        return uas;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure about the lineno ? I would think `userActivations[0];` would trip a (different) warning. What does the `Count()` signature look like? And isn't there a Count property?

Comment: I am very sure about the line number, its not the userActivations[0], or so the ide would have us believe. The Count() signature is simply the IEnumerable Count()... public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);

Comment: @HenkHolterman It must be the LINQ operator, `int System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)`. I believe it has `requires(source != null)`. Yet I don't understand why it cannot be proven: there is an assumption...

Comment: @Pavel - It probably depends on how `UserActivations` looks.

Comment: Please, post the `UserActivations` class declaration and the `UserActivation.GetUserActivationsByUser` method. In general case it should work. Also, post the version of the Code Contracts you use (can be found on the CC settings page of the project properties window)

Comment: It's strange that you don't get runtime exceptions: `Contract.Ensures` must be put in the contract block - before any other code. Perhaps this is the reason of the verifier's failure. In my case your code won't even compile 8)

Comment: @PavelGatilov I updated the GetUserActivationByUser method so that post condition takes place before the precondition, that seems to resolve a lot of my trouble, thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try using a different method, perhaps avoiding the linq `Enumerable` extension methods.  Doesn't the `UserActivations` class have some method or property of its own to determine how many elements an instance holds?

In any event, you shouldn't use the `Count()` extension method to test whether a sequence is empty, because it will enumerate the entire sequence (if the sequence does not implement `ICollection`).  Or, as Pavel Gatilov pointed out, if the object implements `IQueryable`, Count may unexpectedly execute a database query.

That's not a big deal here, where you expect to have one element, but it could be a big deal in cases where a sequence might regularly have thousands of elements.  Instead, you should use the `Any()` extension method.

Since using `Any()` probably won't change things from the contract analyzer's point of view, though, you should use the UserActivations class's `Count` property (assuming it implements ICollection, for example).

Perhaps you can help the contract analyzer this way:

```
private static UserActivation GetUserActivation(Guid userId) 
{ 
    UserActivations userActivations = UserActivation.GetUserActivationsByUser(userId: userId); 

    IEnumerable<UserActivation> e = (IEnumerable<UserActivation>)userActivations;

    Contract.Assume(e != null); 

    if (e.Count() > 1) // Line Number 161 
        throw new Exception("More then one user action found in database"); 

    return userActivations[0]; 
}
```

A better solution, if you control the `UserActivations` class, would be to add `Contract.Ensures` to `GetUserActivationsByUser` to say that the method will never return null.

Comment: You are wrong. `Count()` is OK if the `IEnumerable` instance is actually an `ICollection`: its implementation checks if the instance implements `ICollection` and if it does, returns the `Count` property value instead of enumerating the sequence.

Comment: And if the instance does not implement `ICollection`, then using `Count()` is bad for another reason: if it's an `IQueryable`, then `Count()` may execute a DB query, which might be unexpected.

Comment: @PavelGatilov if the programmer knows that the type implements ICollection, then wouldn't it be better to call the ICollection count property directly?  Using `Count() > 0` is a bad habit that leads to `Count()` being called on non-collection enumerables.  I've most frequently seen it used on Where iterators, which do not have a Count property.  And if the Where condition is computationally expensive, performance is terrible.

Comment: @PavelGatilov thanks, I'll add the IQueryable bit to the answer.

Comment: Good and bad habbits are not the question's topic. My comments relate to the fact that you've claimed that `Count()` enumerates the source, while it does not necesarilly do that. On the other hand, in most cases the real reason of performance hit related to inappropriate usage of `Count()` is not having big sequences, but having sequences that do long actions upon enumeration, like `IQueryable`s. Having this said, I do agree that LINQ operators should be used with care to avoid double-enumeration.

Comment: @PavelGatilov The userActivations class does issue a database query, and it is expected, essentially I am retrieve all user activation from the database then sifting through them and making sure that there is only one that matches the userID. I did not see a reason to write a new count method when the one provided does the job, though that does not mean that I am right in any way (Im still a new developer)

Comment: @phoog Your answer worked after, but I am still a little confused as to why casting my IEnumerable class as IEnumerable<UserActivation> did the trick.

Comment: @Siegeon I suspect it has something to do with the way the compiler translates the extension method call to IL, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @phoog In any case I took your other piece of advise and and made the UserActivations class responsible for ensuring that the method will never return null.

Answer (score 2):

Check your build log. You are using `Contract.Ensures` incorrectly. You should have a warning for the incorrect usage, like this one:

> warning CC1025: CodeContracts: After contract block, found use of local variable 'dataEvents' defined in contract block

Your method should be:

```
public static UserActivations GetUserActivationsByUser(User user = null, Guid userId = new Guid())
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<UserActivations>() != null);

    Guid id = new Guid();
    if (user != null)
        id = user.Id;
    else
        if (userId != Guid.Empty)
            id = userId;
        else
            throw new Exception("Either user or userId must have a value");

    UserActivations uas = new UserActivations(StorageManager.SelectAll(
        Criteria.And(
        Criteria.EqualTo("UserId", id),
        Criteria.EqualTo("Deleted", false))));

    return uas;
}
```

I cannot prove, but I suppose this might make the verifier mad.

In fact, if I turn on run-time checks, your code won't even compile: the ccrewrite will fail.

Comment: I already updated my method to ensure that the post condition is up at the top, thank you again.

Comment: @Siegeon Yeah, I've seen. I just wanted to pull this out so that everyone could see the reason. If your issues are solved, I'd better returned your original code so that others could see the original, broken one.